# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll in VS

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm having this problem I have to solve it by monday (I'm new to C# and VS)
so this is my code:

```
public partial class Add_Delete_Domain : Form
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlDataAdapter da;


    public Add_Delete_Domain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=" + @"C:\Users\Avi\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FriendsProject1\FriendsAdminForm\FriendsDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
```

as you can see im just trying to open the DB and im getting this error message

BTW the line of code above looks like this after i took the code from someone else and putted my DB path.
when im taking my connection string from the DB properties all the ling of code is errors/ this is what happen when i take my connection string:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your connection string

```
con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=" + @"C:\Users\Avi\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FriendsProject1\FriendsAdminForm\FriendsDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
```

or a mall formed connection string string.
    C:\Users\Avi\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FriendsProject1\FriendsAdminForm\FriendsDB.mdf

or permission issue:

```
Integrated Security=True
```

use visual studio to create the connection string for you.
Follow these steps:

Go to View (on menu) => server explorer =>

(This will open up your server navigation tree.)

Right click Data Connections  => add Connection.

Follow the steps for .mdf  type connection.

(This will create the proper connection string (in your config file))

Comment: Yeah, it looks weird somehow, take a look at [this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) it might help you a little. Ha seems that's may be where you got the connection string from. Are you missing database=<YourDatabase>?